# js: how to filter out the repeat item from a two dimensional Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat

Is there any way can solve the below problem:
this is the origin data:

```
var m = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]]
var n = ["a","d","e", "h"]
```

I want to get the data:

```
[["a"], ["d","e"], ["h"]]
```

I've tried：

```
function remove(arr, val) { 
    arr.forEach(v => {
        var index = v.indexOf(val); 
        if (index === -1) { 
            v.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });       
};
n.forEach(val=>{
    remove(m, val);
})
console.log(m)
```

But i faild....
Is there a solution to solve the problem??

Answer (score 4):

If you're OK with a new array, you can `map` and `filter` `m` by whether the item being iterated over is included in `n`:

```js
var m = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]]
var n = ["a","d","e", "h"]

const filteredM = m.map(
  arr => arr.filter(
    item => n.includes(item)
  )
);
console.log(filteredM);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end of the array and splice not common items.

It is necessary to start from the end, because splice (in this case) changes the length of the array and the actual index, if iterating from start.

```js
var m = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]],
    n = ["a", "d", "e", "h"];

m.forEach(a => {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (!n.includes(a[i])) {
            a.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
});

console.log(m); // [["a"], ["d", "e"], ["h"]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var m = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]];
var n = ["a","d","e", "h"];
const newarr = m.map(val => val.filter(element => n.includes(element)));
console.log(newarr);
```